# I have an error in the in the overlay.dart file when compliling the flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, overlay

when building my flutter project that was compiling perfectly without any problem before but since yesterday i got that problem [image]
ans i did all what i could do by upgrading the packages and the flutter itself, but the problem isn't solved

so if anyone face the same problem or have a solution for this problem i would be very thankful

Comment: try to check the `sdk`  version of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get the error is `Overlay.of(context)` could be null. Nullable object should access its field with `?.`.

Replace `Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject()` with `Overlay.of(context)?.context?.findRenderObject()` will do the fix.